# Display the Authors and commit message for commits that cause a conflict

Tags: git, git-commit

I have two long-running branches `dev`, and a far future release called `future` .  We create fixes for the supported release by branching from the tag that exhibits the bug, fix it, and then open pull-requests to the two branches. If there is a conflict in the 'future' branch, our developers are suppose to create a new branch, resolve the conflicts, and open another PR to future.

Unfortunately, our team is large enough that plenty of these second PRs haven't been made.  I need to now figure out which exact commits caused conflicts.  I can do this manually by running git blame on each conflicted file, and seeing the commits on each side of the `======` line, but that doesn't actually give me enough information, and I have to manually run git blame for every conflict and every file.

Is there an easier way?  Ideally, I'd want something equivalent to:

```
Commit X: <coworker1> I updated something.
Commit Y: <coworker2> Something fixed.
Conflicts: 
   some/file/here
   a/different/file.
```

for every single conflict.

Though anything that just gives me the list of conflicting commits would be useful enough to warrant the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

You can get pretty close very easily:

```
git ls-files -u | cut -f2- | uniq \
| while read conflicted; do
        echo @@@ conflicted file $conflicted touched in this merge by:
        git log HEAD...MERGE_HEAD --left-right --format='    %h %aN %s' -- "$conflicted"
done
```

and really, it's only the right-branch (the one being merged in) commit authors you care about -- the left-branch ones have already been merged, let whoever touched what you've already got sort it out.

Add `--topo-order` to the log command to list the commits for each branch together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please elaborate the code you have written? Looks like it is not working (at least for me).

Comment: @RajPawanGumdal there was a `| cut -f2- | uniq` left out

Answer (score 3):

You could run `git diff --diff-filter=U` while merging to see diff output for all (and only) unmerged files. It's still with file content, but it's better than manually running a command for each file.

Comment: That's useful to know, but it doesn't help.  My goal is to have the team member(s) who caused the conflict to work it out. I don't want to resolve it myself unless I have to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start using **git rerere**.
You have to resolve the conflict once, but for almost every new rebase the old merge will do it automatically then. Sometimes you'll need to do a `git rebase --skip`.

https://medium.com/@porteneuve/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
git config rerere.autoupdate true
mkdir .git/rr-cache
```

With many coworkers add the .git/rr-cache dir to your project.

```
ln -s .git/rr-cache .git-rr-cache
git add .git-rr-cache
```

Comment: This looks promising.

Comment: It's not the exact answer to the problem, sorry, but it's a huge help for your workflow problem.
I can work now with many branches and don't have to worry about conflicting merges when rebasing it onto new bases. I even automated it.

Sometime I'll have to give a presentation on "How to maintain a fork in git" or "How I rebase daily my >10 dev branches".

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider using a review tool such as gerrit, which detects possible merge conflicts prior to submitting a change list to a branch. I realize this doesn't help you right this second, but I believe you'll have to write a tool yourself to do what you want.