# Finding out the exact conflicting commit in an attempted merge between 2 branches in github

Tags: github, merge, branch, conflict

How to find out the exact commit where a merge is failing in github. I was looking at the API in github for merging but it does not give us the exact conflicting commit.

Any ideas on that

Comment: The conflict happened when you tried to form a single commit from the HEAD commits of both branches involved.  What are you trying to find here?

Comment: Lets say there is a script or may be a job in jenkins that automatically merges 2 branches if there is a commit in one of the branches to keep both branches in sync. Now lets say a merge conflict occurs. I would like to figure out the exact 2 commits(in the 2 branches) where the conflict occurred. Basically I would like to inform the authors of the 2 commits and ask them to resolve among themselves

Answer (score 0):

Rajdeep,

As TimBiegeleisen said, the conflict when merging two branches is always the most recent commit on each branch.

Reading between the lines, I suspect you want to know which commit actually . If that is what you want to know, then this answer may get you on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31242553/2374880
Specifically, running:

```
git ls-files -u \
| while read conflicted; do
    echo @@@ conflicted file $conflicted touched in this merge by:
    git log HEAD...MERGE_HEAD --left-right --format='    %h %aN %s' -- "$conflicted"
done
```

If you only want the commit id and not the other info, replace the format string argument with just `'%h'`.